# Start and Interrupt and Again Start a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-threading

i started a thread when activity created in android

when click stop it will interrupt the thread to see my data on particular time after that i start the thread by clicking button start
it will start the thread again

sometime it work properly,
sometime i get Interrupted error,

```
strt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Drawer.start();
   });
    stp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Drawer.interrupt();  });
```

what to do?

Comment: Assuming `Drawer` is a Thread, you can't start it twice: ["It is never legal to start a thread more than once"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start())

Comment: @AndyTurner I start that after i interrupt the thread..is that good to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Drawer` is a Thread, you can't start it twice: ["It is never legal to start a thread more than once"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()). Your basic assumptions about how to write this code are flawed.

I would suggest not using threads directly. Instead. Use an `ExecutorService`, for example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Then, submit work to this pool in your start button's onClickListener:

```
future = executor.submit(runnable);
```

where `runnable` is the work you want to do.

The returned `Future` is a thing which conveys the result of running `runnable`, but also lets you do things like cancel it (i.e. ask it to stop running):

```
future.cancel(true);
```

where `true` means that you want to interrupt the underlying thread which is running it.

Hence, store `future` in a member variable when you press the start button, and then cancel it as above when you press the stop button.

Note that you need to make your runnable handle interruption: this is not something which happens "for free". Interruption is a cooperative mechanism: code is free to respond to interruption (or not).